# What to use for real-time chat application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, socket.io, real-time, faye

Im developing a chat application just like omegle.com with some more features for my college project. I want to know which would be the best approach from following two and why:-

1. NodeJS + Socket.io
2. Rails + Faye

I searched a lot on these two and somewhere it says about 1st option and some 2nd. (mostly 2nd)

Please help me here because im little confused which to use as im searching and reading on internet from past one week and didnt come up to any conclusion and already wasted my lot of time.

Any suggestions might do as it would help me to kickstart my project.
(**Note:-** If there is any other approach then please suggest it.)
Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897267/240443 for Faye vs. Socket.io by Faye's author. Also note that Faye can do both Ruby and Node.js.

Comment: Look into XMPP, it is an open source protocol for messenging(used in pidgin or google talk). There is a lot of library supporting it in various  languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can also prefer this:

https://github.com/ciserfan/cis_rails_chat

This is good gem to implement chat.

Answer (score 3):

I just released a gem for this called Entangled:

https://github.com/so-entangled/rails

It basically enables two way data binding between your front end and back end, meaning new data or changes to existing data will be pushed to all connected clients in real time. A chat app should be easy to build with it.

Comment: This... this is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rails + Faye as you will have more features out of the box using Faye.

NodeJS + SocketIO will lead you to develop much of what you have with Faye. So why wasting this time?

If you want to use NodeJS as "app server" try to look for something equivalent to Faye such as [Chat.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chat.io)